# How to connect to nest camera IoT device from UWP app ?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

i have NEST camera installed in the living room and the API provided by NEST does not have an approach to video stream the data. Therefore i am trying to use some external tool to make it work. That's where i read about UWP app that helps to connect to numerous devices including IoT.

Now i am stuck with how to connect the device ? when i try to give the IP address to find the device, didnt actually help. May be my approach is wrong.

If anybody have ever done this or has any idea about this, would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bhuvi

Answer (score 0):

You need use [web_url](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-camera#web_url) api provided by NEST firstly,the returned result is web url to the live video stream at home.nest.com,then you can use this web url to get video stream.